# How does Dalvik VM get access to I/O?

Tags: android, native, dalvik, forth

I have recently become interested in the [Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29). From Wikipedia and some slides I got know basic information about Dalvik VM. There's still things I don't know, and I can't find documents easily, like:

How does Dalvik VM get access to I/O?

I don't see any opcode that calls a native method. Those opcodes which are named with a prefix, "OP_INVOKE", seems they are all invoke a method that in .dex files (Dalvik Executable files). Maybe I checked the wrong version of opcodes describe?)

BTW, is there any user friendly Forth implementation on Android?

I have tried AndroidForth which does not support `dup`!

Comment: Re. Forth: [jsForth](http://www.forthfreak.net/jsforth.html) is presently your best bet, although with some limitations that you might lift with PhoneGap or like.  [Retro](http://retroforth.org/) (which, contrary to the name, is not 'retro' to anything, especially not Forth; it's just a vaguely Forth-inspired language) has an Android UI through PhoneGap.  Your options for on-device programming are fairly lame, compared to PalmOS.

Comment: well i have retro installed on my phone, the problem is that its just for playing , i want to mkae real but simple tools on android

Comment: Then nothing exists yet for you.  The most reasonable path (aside from 'give up and use some other language', which is what I went with) is to have your Forth system generate Java.

Answer (score 3):

The standard "invoke" opcodes you mention can be used to invoke a native method - it doesn't care.

In this sense, a native method is a method in a java class that has been marked with the "native" specifier, and is implemented in a native library, following the standard JNI model for java.

Here are some more details on JNI in dalvik/Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/jni.html

Comment: well i dont want to has relation ship with java class, can it invoke just native c method directly? without java language's bridage?

Comment: The only way to call a native method from dalvik bytecode is through JNI.